# Why is there a 1px spacing between this div and its contents

Tags: html, css, media-queries

The "featured music" area has a margin of 1px on the right side of the iframe. Its inside the `.shadow` div. You can see it on the h2 because it goes out 1px passed the other content. The `.shadow` div wraps the 1px margin, as well. I don't know why it is doing this.

I did notice that this only applies to when the screen is using the css in here `@media screen and (min-width: 59.6875em) { }`. When its smaller that 1px problem goes away.

Here is the site I'm working on: [website](http://outlatemgmt.com/)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's coming from the .widget class.  The properties are set to `border:1px solid #e5e5e5`.

Comment: I just noticed something. that doesn't fix the h2 1px spacing. only the 1px box-shadow one

Comment: That's just because the h2 is a regular rectangle while the container beneath it has rounded corners.  A rectangle on a circle will always have gaps.